# Without use of derivatives, prove that $e^{-x}\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ is strictly decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

> Prove,  without use of derivatives, that function $x\mapsto e^{-x}\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ is strictly decreasing.

**Attempt.** Functions $x\mapsto x^ne^{-x}$ for $n=0,1,2$ are not  strictly decreasing (in order to guarantee that their sum is decreasing). Working separately on $e^{-x},~~1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ didn't work also, since $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ is not decreasing on the reals. I am looking for an elementary way to prove it (it's derivative is $-\frac{e^{-x}x^2}{2}<0$ for $x\neq 0$).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Without derivatives, how do you define $e^{-x}$?

Comment: $e^x>1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2$ on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Are we allowed to render $e>(1+(1/n))^n$ for all positive $n$?

Comment: If you write down the power series of $e^{-x}$ and multiply, may be you will find a sum of 3 decreasing functions.

Comment: @JoséAlejandroAburtoAraneda How does one compute the power series without using derivatives?

Comment: "Without use of derivatives" implied that I don't want to use the criterion using the first derivative to get the monotonicity of the desired function. Powerseries of $e^x$ is allowed, if needed. (also $(1+1/n)^n\to e$ ).

Comment: @saulspatz You don't need differentiation to define power series; so you can define the exponential function with it's power series.

Comment: use that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ is strictly increasing and $e^x$ is the limit of this so $e^x>(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ for $x\ne 0$

Comment: If you have not power series you have not exponential. It is usually defined as the power series without requiring the derivative

Comment: @saulspatz so, how do you define the exponential. If you have not power series, how? If you have not definition of exponential you cannot solve the problem about something not defined

Comment: @JoséAlejandroAburtoAraneda I would define it as the inverse of the natural logarithm, which is, in turn, defined by a definite integral.  I agree that taking the power series as the definition is legitimate, but I didn't realize that was what the OP was doing.

Comment: And how do you define the log

Comment: You won't catch me that way again! [Proof (without use of differential calculus) that $e^{\sqrt{x}}$ is convex on $[1,+\infty)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3114933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume the properties $e^x > 1 +x + \frac{x^2}{2}$ and  $e^{x+y} = e^x e^y$ are given.

For $x+h > x > 0$, we have $\left(h+ \frac{h^2}{2}\right)\left(1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}\right)> h + xh+\frac{h^2}{2}$, and, hence,

$$e^h > 1+ h + \frac{h^2}{2} > 1 + \frac{h + xh+\frac{h^2}{2}}{1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}} = \frac{1 + (x+h)+\frac{(x+h)^2}{2}}{1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Thus,

$$1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2} > e^{-h}\left(1 + (x+h)+\frac{(x+h)^2}{2} \right)$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^{-x}$ we get

$$e^{-x}\left(1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}\right) > e^{-(x+h)}\left(1 + (x+h)+\frac{(x+h)^2}{2} \right)$$

Something similar should work for the case $x < 0$.